# NgbDatePicker set default time zone

Tags: angular, browser, timezone

i have an angular app using ng-bootstrap. I have a ngbdatepicker and works fine.
But if i change the timezone in my browser, the ngbdatepicker takes the time of the browser as time zone.

I want to make a default time zone for the whole application as if different people arround the world select a date, it will be always based on their local settings and will be displayed differently for other users.

Is there any way to force ngbdatepicker to use a specific time zone? not the one from browser?

Cheers